# keytool.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: java, windows, keytool

Whenever I use any of those commands, I get "keytool.exe is not a valid win32 application" error, even when I open `keytool.exe` independently as an exe file.

1. `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre6\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\ti7a\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android`
2. `keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\ti7a\.android\debug.keystore"`
3. `C:>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin`

   and then

   `keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -key store "C:\Users\ti7a\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass andro id -keypass android`

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is a confusing error message. I'm not sure if it's a bug in JRE/JDK or not, but you seem to be using Windows 64bit with a 32bits JRE (as `x86` part in program files map indicates). Try installing Windows 64bit version of the JRE/JRK.

Comment: i tried  on widows xp 32 bit but this appeared again may be its the problem with jdk @BalusC

Comment: What version of Windows exactly are you using? (press winkey+pause to see detail) What version of Java exactly are you using? (use `java -version`).

Comment: i am using win 7 64 bit SP1 with the latest updates (autoupdate) @BalusC

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem. I found another keytool.exe inside of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin"
I guess you used the keytool.exe inside of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"

Wolfen

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I looked at the size of the EXE file, and its size was 0kb.

After a bunch of research, I came across a this:
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/x64bits.xml

It says to install the 32bit version to fix the problem. However I didn't like that idea, so I re-installed the 64bit version and it fixed the problem form me.

You might want to check the size of your file to see if this could be your problem.

Comment: Do you know what caused `java.exe` corruption? Failed update, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I copied keytool.exe from another server and replaced it on the machine throwing this error and that worked for me.